# Using hyph-utf8 with plain TeX

Tags: pdftex, hyphenation, unicode, plain-tex

I want to use the UTF-8 hyphenation patterns (for Croatian) with plain TeX (pdftex). I've read the documentation on the hyph-utf8 package but I haven't found it very useful. There's mention of a `\uselanguage{langname}` command but I don't know where to put it.

When I tried putting the command in the text file I'm trying to process, an e-TeX error occurs saying `language hr is undefined` (also tried with other languages, like US English, and none of them is recognised; also tried full language names like croatian, etc.).

When I try to use the command during format generation, the error "command is undefined" occurs.

I've tried directly including the `loadhyph-hr.tex` file (found in hyph-utf8 package) in the `.tex` file I use to create a format, that failed too.

Does anyone know how to make this work?

***EDIT***:
This is what my format-generating file (`F.tex`) looks like now:

```
\let\keptdump\dump \let\dump\relax    
\input pdfetex.ini
\let\enc=u
\input csplain.ini
\let\dump\keptdump \let\keptdump=\undefined
\dump
```

where `csplain.ini` is a file in encTeX with the following content:

```
\input csfonts  % re-defines primitive \font
\input plain    % format Plain
\restorefont    % original meaning of primitive \font
\input il2code  % extra codes for czech / slovak letters in ISO-8859-2 encoding
\input hyphen.lan  % czech / slovak hyphenation pattern (may be others too)
\input plaina4  % \hsize and \vsize for A4
\everyjob=\expandafter{\the\everyjob
   \message{The format: csplain <Sep. 2005>.}
   \message{The cs-fonts are preloaded and A4 size implicitly defined.}}
\ifx\enc\undefined \else \input csenc-\enc.tex \fi % re-encoding using encTeX
\ifx\xprncode\undefined \else %% The encTeX is detected
   \count255=128               % All codes > 128 are printable: 
   \loop \xprncode\count255=1 \advance\count255 by 1
   \ifnum \count255<256 \repeat
\fi

\ifx\pdfoutput\undefined \else % added in Feb. 2005
   \def\tmpa{\pdfcsplain}
   \expandafter\def\expandafter\tmpb\expandafter{\csname\jobname\endcsname}
   \ifx\tmpa\tmpb %% PDFTeX with PDF output
      \message {jobname=pdfcsplain, PDF output initialised.}
      \openin0=pdftexconfig.tex
      \ifeof0 \message{WARNING: pdftexconfig.tex does not exist. 
                       I set \string\pdfoutput=1 only.}%
      \else \closein0 \input pdftexconfig.tex
      \fi
      \pdfoutput=1
   \else
      \message {jobname=csplain with pdftex, DVI output initialised.}
      \pdfoutput=0
      \let\oripdfoutput=\pdfoutput \let\pdfoutput=\undefined
   \fi
   \let\tmpa=\undefined \let\tmpb=\undefined
\fi

\dump
```

I haven't changed anything in this file, but I have modified files `csfonts` and `csenc-u`.

Comment: It depends on your TeX distribution: in TeX Live the `\uselanguage{croatian}` works with the preloaded format with pdftex, xetex and luatex. Note that you can't directly use UTF-8 input with plain TeX, unless you change fonts and probably do some tricks to get the right result.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have TeXLive 2009. I've made some modifications to the encTeX package so that I can process UTF-8 input files in Croatian with pdftex directly. But I still can't use UTF-8 hyphenation patterns, neither using the encTeX-made format nor using plain format.

Just to be clear, what exactly do you mean by "preloaded format"? Maybe I'm missing something...

Answer (score 6):

Since you have TeX Live (on a Unix system, I guess), you should have the language available: a UTF-8 encoded file

```
\uselanguage{croatian}
\font\tenrm="Latin Modern Roman/S=10;mapping=tex-text"

\tenrm\hsize=1pt

\hskip0pt Republika Hrvatska Položajem

\bye
```

processed with xetex should show hyphenation as `Re-pu-bli-ka Hr-vat-ska Po-lo-ža-jem`.

Are you sure to have installed the support files for Croatian, that is, the Debian package `texlive-lang-croatian`?

Note that using plain TeX with pdftex won't give correct results, unless the default fonts are changed and some catcode trickery is performed or encTeX is used.

You need to prepare your format with

```
pdftex -ini -enc -etex -pdf "\def\enc{u}\input F.tex"
```

where `F.tex` is

```
\input csfonts  % re-defines primitive \font

\let\keptdump\dump \let\dump\relax
\input pdfetex.ini

\restorefont    % original meaning of primitive \font
\input il2code  % extra codes for czech / slovak letters in ISO-8859-2 encoding
\input plaina4  % \hsize and \vsize for A4
\everyjob=\expandafter{\the\everyjob
   \message{The format: csplain <Sep. 2005>.}
   \message{The cs-fonts are preloaded and A4 size implicitly defined.}}
\input csenc-u.tex % re-encoding using encTeX
\ifx\xprncode\undefined \else %% The encTeX is detected
   \count255=128               % All codes > 128 are printable: 
   \loop \xprncode\count255=1 \advance\count255 by 1
   \ifnum \count255<256 \repeat
\fi

\ifnum\pdfoutput=0
  \message {jobname=csplain with pdftex, DVI output initialised.}
  \pdfoutput=0
  \let\oripdfoutput=\pdfoutput \let\pdfoutput=\undefined
\else
  \message {jobname=pdfcsplain, PDF output initialised.}
    \openin0=pdftexconfig.tex
    \ifeof0 \message{WARNING: pdftexconfig.tex does not exist. 
                     I set \string\pdfoutput=1 only.}%
    \else \closein0 \input pdftexconfig.tex
    \fi
    \pdfoutput=1
\fi

\let\dump\keptdump \let\keptdump=\undefined
\dump
```

Here I assume that your modifications to `csfonts.tex` and `csenc-u.tex` are consistent with your purposes.

Comment: Oh boy... I didn't have it installed; I thought hyph-utf8 would be enough. This worked when processed as `pdftex file.tex`, even though the characters weren't printed right (as expected). Thank you!! 

Still, when I generate a format F using the -enc option (which I need for utf8 inputting of Croatian characters) and try to run `pdftex \&F file.tex`, I get the error "Undefined control sequence...\uselanguage" again.

If you would happen to have an idea why this happens, please let me know... In any case, thanks very much for your help!

Comment: I've added the instruction for preparing correctly a format that knows about `\uselanguage`.

Comment: I get a "Duplicate pattern" error while processing this:


...


(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/hyphen/hyphen.tex


! Duplicate pattern.


l.6 .ach4


(that's the first entry in the hyphen.tex file)

Comment: You shouldn't load `plain.tex` in your customization file `F.tex`, it's already done by `pdfetex.ini`. You can add it to your question, so that we are able to check it.

Comment: I added the files I used to my original post. Thanks again for the suggestions!

Comment: I have changed your file `F.tex`. It should work, now.

Comment: @egreg I noticed that the first word is not hyphenated if \hskip0pt is not used. This is curious. Where in TeXbook is this mentioned?

Comment: @IgorLiferenko Page 454, second doubly dangerous bend: “TeX looks for potentially hyphenatable words by searching ahead from each glue item that is not in a math formula.”

Answer (score 0):

You must add the patterns to the format. For this a suitable line must be added to your local `language.def` and then the formats must be regenerated. E.g. my local version of `language.def` contains beside others these lines

```
\addlanguage{ngerman}{loadhyph-de-1996.tex}{}{2}{2}
\addlanguage{ngerman-x-2009-06-19}{dehyphn-x-2009-06-19.tex}{}{2}{2}
```

In a modern tex installation the language.def is managed through a configuration GUI. E.g. in miktex you should use the tab "languages" in miktex-settings.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it didn't help. I've added such a line in `language.def`, regenerated the format (as in, pdftex'd the format .tex file), tried to process the file with the given format and I got the "Undefined control sequence" error again.
Also, I'm using TeXLive and I don't think there's a GUI where I could manage this.